# eigensolver in eigen Library

Tags: c++, matlab, eigen

I would like to translate  `[vec,val] = eig(A)` from MATLAB to c++ using Eigen library, but I couldn't reach to the same result!
I tried `eigensolver`,`ComplexEigenSolver` and `SelfAdjointEigenSolver.` None of them give me the result like `eig(A)` in MATLAB.

```
Sample matrices:
Tv(:,:,223) =

    0.8648   -1.9658   -0.2785
   -1.9658    4.9142    0.8646
   -0.2785    0.8646    0.3447


Tv(:,:,224) =

    1.9735   -0.4218    1.0790
   -0.4218    3.3012    0.1855
    1.0790    0.1855    3.7751


Tv(:,:,225) =

    2.4948    1.0185    1.1633
    1.0185    1.1732   -0.4479
    1.1633   -0.4479    4.3289


Tv(:,:,226) =

    0.3321    0.0317    0.1617
    0.0317    0.0020   -0.0139
    0.1617   -0.0139    0.5834
```

Eigen:

```
MatrixXcd vec(3 * n, 3);
VectorXcd val(3);
for (int k = 0; k < n; k++){
        EigenSolver<Matrix3d> eig(Tv.block<3, 3>(3 * k, 0));
        vec.block<3, 3>(3 * k, 0) = eig.eigenvectors();
        cout <<endl << vec.block<3, 3>(3 * k, 0) << endl;
        val = eig.eigenvalues();
        cout << "val= " << endl << val << endl;

    }
```

//results

```
  (0.369152,0)   (-0.830627,0)   (-0.416876,0)
  (-0.915125,0)   (-0.403106,0) (-0.00717218,0)
  (-0.162088,0)    (0.384142,0)   (-0.908935,0)
val=
  (5.86031,0)
(0.0396418,0)
 (0.223765,0)

 (0.881678,0)  (0.204005,0)  (0.425472,0)
  (0.23084,0)  (-0.97292,0) (-0.011858,0)
(-0.411531,0) (-0.108671,0)  (0.904894,0)
val=
(1.35945,0)
(3.41031,0)
(4.27996,0)

 (0.526896,0) (-0.726801,0)  (0.440613,0)
(-0.813164,0) (-0.581899,0) (0.0125466,0)
(-0.247274,0)  (0.364902,0)  (0.897609,0)
val=
(0.377083,0)
 (2.72623,0)
 (4.89367,0)

    (0.88992,0)    (-0.43968,0)    (0.121341,0)
    (0.13406,0) (-0.00214387,0)   (-0.990971,0)
   (-0.43597,0)   (-0.898152,0)  (-0.0570358,0)
val=
   (0.257629,0)
   (0.662467,0)
(-0.00267575,0)
```

MATLAB:

```
for k=1:n
    [u,d] = eig(Tv(:,:,k))
end
```

%results

```
u =

    0.8306   -0.4169   -0.3692
    0.4031   -0.0072    0.9151
   -0.3841   -0.9089    0.1621


d =

    0.0396         0         0
         0    0.2238         0
         0         0    5.8603


u =

    0.8817    0.2040    0.4255
    0.2308   -0.9729   -0.0119
   -0.4115   -0.1087    0.9049


d =

    1.3594         0         0
         0    3.4103         0
         0         0    4.2800


u =

   -0.5269    0.7268    0.4406
    0.8132    0.5819    0.0125
    0.2473   -0.3649    0.8976


d =

    0.3771         0         0
         0    2.7262         0
         0         0    4.8937


u =

   -0.1213   -0.8899    0.4397
    0.9910   -0.1341    0.0021
    0.0570    0.4360    0.8982


d =

   -0.0027         0         0
         0    0.2576         0
         0         0    0.6625
```

What's your suggestion?

Comment: my suggestion is to explain what goes wrong!

Comment: I would suggest you test the results to see if they are both correct. You can do that by creating a matrix D, diagonal with the eingenvalues and V, a combination of the eigenvectors. Then compute V^-1*D*V, this should be A or very close to a (due to numerical errors). If its not then you are doing it wrong, if both give A then probably the order of the eigenvectors is different or they are normalized, ....

Comment: What's your input matrix?

Comment: it's not just one matrix. it's in a loop

Comment: Can you edit your question and place at least one example of the matrices?

Comment: @MJARIAN Both of the answers correctly answer the question. Please accept one of them. This rewards both the answerer (+15) and the asker (+2), and helps future visitors get help when encountering similar problems.

Answer (score 5):

I don't get your question, as looking at your results they all returns the same. Recall that the eigen-decomposition of a matrix is not completely unique:

- eigenvalues/vectors can be arbitrarily reordered
- if v is an eigenvector, then -v is also a valid eigenvector

Since your matrices are symmetric, you should use SelfAdjointEigenSolver to get them automatically ordered as MatLab. Then the eigenvectors will only differs from their sign, but you will have to live with that.

Answer (score 1):

Well.... the results are the same....

Result eigen:

```
  (0.369152,0)   (-0.830627,0)   (-0.416876,0)
  (-0.915125,0)   (-0.403106,0) (-0.00717218,0)
  (-0.162088,0)    (0.384142,0)   (-0.908935,0)
val=
  (5.86031,0)
(0.0396418,0)
 (0.223765,0)
```

result matlab:

```
u =

    0.8306   -0.4169   -0.3692
    0.4031   -0.0072    0.9151
   -0.3841   -0.9089    0.1621


d =

    0.0396         0         0
         0    0.2238         0
         0         0    5.8603
```

I have good news....

The vectors are THE SAME, but unordered.....

eigV1 from eigen is -eigV3 from Matlab,

eigV2 from eigen is -eigV1 from Matlab,

eigV3 from eigen is -eigV2 from Matlab,

The eigenvalues are reordered equally....

Comment: but it's not a rule dude!! as you can see for other matrices!

Comment: @MJARIAN oh, of course it isn't! The fact is, that the order of the eigenvectors matters little, so each algorithm decides (who knows how) which vector to put first. The point here is that they are the same, no matter the order they get outputed.

Comment: @MJARIAN what do you need them for? I cant think of an application where the order of the vectors matter.

Comment: by the way 'SelfAdjointEigenSolver' give us the nearest answer to eig MATLAB

Comment: @MJARIAN The answers are the same!!!!! Its just the order of the vectors when building the matrix Vect. If you want them ordered, I suggest you order them by the biggest eigenvalue to the lowest eigenvalue and move the vectors accordingly. That way you make sure that no matter which algorithm you are using for getting the result, you always will have them ordered specifically.

Comment: @MJARIAN Do not forget to accept any of the answers if you found them useful, for future lost eigensolvers!